# Linux: old udev (095) changing device permissions doesn't work

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, udev

I have the following udev rule:

`# f055:9800, 9801, 9802 MicroPython pyboard
ATTRS{idVendor}=="f055", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="f055", ENV{MTP_NO_PROBE}="1"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="f055", MODE="0666"
KERNELS=="ttyACM*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="f055", MODE="0666"`

on CentOS 7(udev 219) it works fine, but on CentOS 5(udev 095) it doesn't change the permission.

Is there maybe a different syntax for old udev versions I am not aware of?

Comment: The kernel configuration file of the CentOS 5 machine: https://bpaste.net/show/d16d8651e79e

Comment: The kernel configuration file of the CentOS 7 machine: https://bpaste.net/show/5022e859c67f